# Setuid, SUID bit not providing root privileges

Tags: permissions, chmod, setuid

I've written and compiled a short program to allow any user to change the contents of my `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` file, but I fail to escalate their permissions. What could I be missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FILENAME "/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int res;
    setuid(0); // I didn't intend to keep this, but I included it just in case
    printf("euid %d\n", geteuid());
    system("whoami");
    // Attempt to open FILENAME; print "Can't open..." on failure
}
```

Yet, `whoami` consistently returns `exampleuser` instead of `root`, and the program consistently fails to open the output file.

I compile it and set the uid bit then run the program:

```
$ gcc -o example.bin example.c     # compile
$ sudo chown root:root example.bin # set owner & group
$ sudo chmod 4770 example.bin      # set uid bit
$ ./example.bin 75                 # execute
euid 1000
exampleuser
Can't open output file /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

The target output file does exist:

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May  2 07:57 /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

*I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS*

Comment: Is the filesystem on which `example.bin` is located mounted with `nosuid`? Also, I suggest `id -a` as a more comprehensive test command instead of `whoami`. I am not sure but I think `who` and/or `whoami` obtain information from `utmp` which could cloud the facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the filesystem is doesn't support setuid executables (because it's mounted with the `nosuid` option, or because it's a FUSE filesystem mounted by a non-root user), or there is a security framework such as SELinux or AppArmor that prevents setuid here (I don't think Ubuntu sets up anything like this though). That, or you didn't actually run these commands — you've made the file non-executable by others, so they'd only work if you were in the `root` group, which you shouldn't be.

This isn't a good way to do it anyway. It's a lot simpler to change the permissions on the file.

```
chgrp users /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
chmod g+w /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Use a group that you're a member of, if you aren't a member of the `users` group.

Add these commands to `/etc/rc.local` or some other script that is executed near the end of the boot sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative design. As for the `nosuid` option, `mount` reveals that the device on which `example.bin` resides has no such restriction: `/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)`. I don't believe I'm using any unusual frameworks except for encryption of the home folder with `encryptfs-utils`.

Comment: I did run the commands, and I am in the `root` group, for better or worse.

Comment: The file I wish to modify, however, is on a device mounted with `nosuid`. I wouldn't expect that to make a difference, but do you know otherwise?

Comment: @JellicleCat Ah, so the file is on a filesystem which doesn't support setuid — it's on ecryptfs (if it's on the encrypted part, it isn't on the `/` filesystem). I forgot to mention that case.

Comment: @JellicleCat Is `example.bin` in your (encrypted) home directory, or on the `/` filesystem? The fact that `/sys` doesn't support setuid is irrelevant.

Comment: It's in my home directory, but `df example.bin` yieilds `/home/exampleuser/.Private`, which is a symlink to `/home/.ecryptfs/exampleyser/.Private`, and `df` on that yields `/dev/sda5`, which is the device mounted at `/`. So isn't that an acceptable filesystem?

Comment: Guess I'm wrong! I just moved the executable to a different location, and it indicates that I'm root when I run it now!

Comment: @JellicleCat `df example.bin` tells you that it's on the filesystem mounted at  `/home/exampleuser/.Private`. The filesystem that this mount point is on is another, unrelated, irrelevant filesystem.